# Qt for iOS development: File read and write

Tags: ios, qt, file

I'm using Qt5.5 for iOS development.

I'm wondering how to find and open a file in an iOS device to read and write using Qt5.5. As I know, there's no such file tree structure in iOS. When I download a picture, for example, I even do not know where it locates. But I can see it in apps.

Is there anyone can help? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert with Qt, but I believe you need the [`QStandardPaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) class.

iOS is no different to any other platform that stores files in certain pre-defined locations.